DocumentGroup's back button dismisses the sheet instead of closing the document
Setup to reproduce:
I have a simple document-based app which is wrapped in a DocumentGroup:
App.swift
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

@main
struct BugtestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: TextDocument()) { _ in
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

The TextDocument struct looks like this if you want to reproduce this for yourself:
TextDocument.swift
struct TextDocument: FileDocument {
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] = [.text, .plainText]
    
    init() { }
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws { }
    
    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        .init()
    }
}

In my ContentView I have a .sheet with .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled).
ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Background")
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                Text("Sheet")
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])
                    .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
            }
    }
}

My Problem:
When tapping the DocumentGroup's built-in back button it dismisses the sheet.
What I expected to happen:
I expected it to close the document and save it as it would if the sheet wasn't present.
What I tried:

I've found that I can programatically go back using UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true). So I've tried to detect if the sheet is dismissed while it shouldn't have. Meaning that the back button was pressed, and go one layer deeper this way. Nevertheless, I couldn't get it to work reliably. .sheet's onDismiss is also called in other situations.
I've tried to create a custom back button for the DocumentGroup, I could get a custom back button to show up. Using .toolbar, But I couldn't hide the built-in back button using .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(). Apparently it doesn't work for DocumentGroup's back button.


Any help or ideas on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated!

I bet the back button calls dismiss which is being handled by the sheet https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss you might need to leave presentationBackgroundInteraction false and redesign

I'm afraid you seem to be right. I've moved away from using a sheet and created a custom implementation instead.
